# How can I change my turtlebot2 working in Kinect+Odometry configurations

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect, turtlebot2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use Turtlebot2 to launch demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch file, my robot's configurations is Kinect+Odometry+Fake 2D laser from Kinect。
But I want to put my robot into Kinect+Odometry,and I want to create with rtabmap node with proj_map topic a 2D occupancy grid map from the projection of the Kinect. How do I modify the demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch file.
I refer to wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_Odometry
github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/demo/demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246207/how-can-i-change-my-turtlebot2-working-in-kinect+odometry-configurations/) by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-10-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this [post](http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Demo-RTAB-Map-on-Turtlebot-td439i40.html#a2189):

In [demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/demo/demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch):

-Set all "subscribe_scan" to false. This is optional though, you can keep the laser scan if you want.

-Change these lines:

```
<remap from="proj_map" to="/map"/> <!-- use projection map, use "grid_map" for version > 0.11.8 -->
<param name="Reg/Strategy" type="string" value="0"/> <!-- laser scan not used anymore for registration -->
<param name="Vis/MinInliers" type="string" value="20"/> <!-- default is 20 -->
<param name="Grid/FromDepth" type="string" value="true"/> <!-- For version > 0.11.8 only: Not required if subscribe_scan is false -->
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on 2016-10-24**:
Sometimes,terminal displays Rejected loop closure 92 -> 233: Not enough inliers 0/20 or 3/20 between 233 and 92.
Should I decrease the value of this?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-10-25**:
The parameter above is set to 20. Setting below 10 would result in poor registration. That warning tells just that a loop closure is detected, but there are not enough good matches to find a good transformation between the locations. So it is better to reject it.

**Comment by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on 2016-10-25**:
Thank you very much.

**Comment by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on 2016-11-02**:
“That warning tells just that a loop closure is detected, but there are not enough good matches to find a good transformation. So it is better to reject it.” Then the robot is rotating and doesn't move to goal. But it can move to a nearby location.How can I let the robot move to a goal directly?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-11-02**:
Not sure to understand what you mean. The warning you quoted is independent of the move_base problem.

**Comment by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on 2016-11-02**:
When the warning is appearing, the robot start rotating. And I don't know why.